# Failing to compile achemso style document

Tags: bibtex, achemso

I am trying to compile my tex document for the achemso style.
I have read through the achemso manual and I think I got it right.
I am using texstudio and this is how I compile the document:

Default compiler: `txs:///pdflatex | txs:///bibtex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex`

Here is a (I think) MWE of my code:

```
\documentclass[journal = jprobs, manuscript = article, layout = twocolumn]{achemso}
%Math and font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

%Dependecies of achemso
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hypdoc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{microtype}
%Requeirments
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

%Achemos package
\usepackage{achemso}

%Meta data
%First author
\author{a1}
\affiliation[af1]{af1}
\alsoaffiliation[af2]{af2}
\email{e1}
%Last author
\author{a2}
\affiliation[af1]{af1}
\alsoaffiliation[af2]{af2}
\email{e2}

\title[Shorter title here]{Overly pompous title here}


\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}
        A short description of the paper
    \end{abstract}
    Hello world!\cite{einstein}
    \begin{acknowledgement}
        People who helped us gets credits here
    \end{acknowledgement}
    \bibliographystyle{achemso}
    \bibliography{Cite}
    \begin{suppinfo}
        Supplemental information is put here
    \end{suppinfo}
\end{document}
```

And my Cite.bib looks like this:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
```

Running only Bibtex on this code generates this error:

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "MWE"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.3)
The top-level auxiliary file: MWE.aux
The style file: achemso.bst
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 25 of file MWE.aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {achemso}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: acs-MWE.bib
Database file #2: Cite.bib
achemso 2021-01-20 v3.13c
(There was 1 error message)

Process exited with error(s)
```

If I remove the `\bibliographystyle{achemso}` this error disappears but I still get the following error (with or without the `\bibliographystyle{achemso}`):

```
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@BOOKMARK was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.1 \BOOKMARK [\par
                    ][\tex_par:D <0 ]{bib1.\par }\sloppy  \clubpenalty 4000\...
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

This error is followed by a barrage of errors.
There is no error if I remove the `\cite{einstein}`, `bibliographystyle{achemso}`, and `\bibliography{Cite}`.
So I suspect it has something to do with compiling the bibliography.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `achemso` automatically sets the bibliography style to the appropriate style for your class settings, so you won't need `\bibliographystyle{achemso}` and indeed should not have that line in your document. That explains the first error.

Comment: You won't need to load the packages listed as required in the documentation explicitly in the preamble. `achemso` already does that for you. You also (probably) don't need to and should not load the packages listed as dependency for the documentation. Remove those two blocks of packages completely.

Comment: With the `achemso` class in use, you should not load `\usepackage{achemso}` (in fact the package will just abort loading).

Comment: With those issues fixed your document becomes https://gist.github.com/moewew/c214df6b50abc2443d9bfcb17597afdb which compiles fine for me. (The second error you were getting was caused by `\usepackage{hypdoc}`.)

Comment: Ah, I was confused if I should load those things or not, thanks for clarifying! It works fine for me as well now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`achemso` automatically sets the bibliography style to the appropriate style for your class settings, so you won't need `\bibliographystyle{achemso}` and indeed should not have any `\bibliographystyle` in a document using `achemso` class at all. That explains the first error.

The second error specifically seems to be caused by `\usepackage{hypdoc}`.

- You don't need to load the packages listed as required in the documentation in the preamble explicitly. Those packages will be automatically loaded by the class.
- You should not load the packages listed as dependencies of the `achemso` *documentation* indiscriminately, unless you explicitly need one of them.

With these changes applied to your document, here is how it could look like

```
\documentclass[journal = jprobs, manuscript = article, layout = twocolumn]{achemso}
%Math and font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

%Meta data
%First author
\author{a1}
\affiliation[af1]{af1}
\alsoaffiliation[af2]{af2}
\email{e1}
%Last author
\author{a2}
\affiliation[af1]{af1}
\alsoaffiliation[af2]{af2}
\email{e2}

\title[Shorter title here]{Overly pompous title here}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}
        A short description of the paper
    \end{abstract}
    Hello world!\cite{einstein}
    \begin{acknowledgement}
        People who helped us gets credits here
    \end{acknowledgement}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
    \begin{suppinfo}
        Supplemental information is put here
    \end{suppinfo}
\end{document}
```

this compiles without error.